# How to check if subMenu is shown without setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I've got a problem. I have some submenus on my website that i show and hide with jQuery. 
The #Sekundar is the submenu, but what i want to ask about is, Is there a better way to check if the menu is shown or not shown?

I couldn't get it make it work unless i put a setInterval on it, and that isn't the best way of doing it i think? Any suggestions?

Here is the JS code:

```
function sekundarmenu() {
    $('#sekundar').fadeToggle();
    $('#sekundar2').hide();
    $('#sekundar3').hide();
    $('#sekundar4').hide();
    $('#sekundar5').hide();
}

setInterval(function () {
    if ($("#sekundar").is(":visible") || $("#sekundar").css("display")== "block") {
        $("#li1").css("background-color", "#24ac5f");
    }
    else {
        $("#li1").css("background-color", "transparent");
    }
}, 1);
```

And the HTML:

```
<nav id="primar">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="li1"><a onclick="sekundarmenu()" class="pointer">Indhold</a></li>
                        <li id="li2"><a onclick="sekundarmenu2()" class="pointer">Nyheder</a></li>
                        <li id="li3"><a onclick="sekundarmenu3()" class="pointer">Billeder</a></li>
                        <li id="li4"><a onclick="sekundarmenu4()" class="pointer">Bruger</a></li>
                        <li id="li5"><a onclick="sekundarmenu5()" class="pointer">Diverse</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <div id="sekundar" class="sekundar">
                <nav class="nav2">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Opret Tekster</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rediger/Slet tekster</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rediger kontakt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

Comment: When you want to show or hide? Is there any event triggering this? Or you want to keep checking it always?

Comment: Yes there is a onclick event on my menu links. I want it to check if the submenu is open when it is opened and the same the other way.

Comment: What's the structure of the menu and submenu in html

Comment: The HTML is now added in the question

Comment: check http://jsbin.com/koruqu/1/edit, is this what are you looking for?

Comment: Yea a little bit..Like this --> http://jsfiddle.net/SLRK6/ 

But if i select one and clicks another, and then clicks the one i've selected first, i have to click 2 times before it reacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are many ways to solve similar problems you have to choose the one that best suits your case.
in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/7bFUa/)
i thought to solve the problem in another way by adding some classes in your html code.
 In this way the jQuery code is drastically reduced.
I also added the ability to disappear the submenu on mouseleave, if you don't like this solution you can easily delete the lines of code highlighted in the fiddle.
If you like this solution remember to flag in green my answer ;)
all jQuery code you need is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('li.principal').click(function(){
        var whatSubmenu=$(this).attr('id').slice(1)
        $('li.principal').css("background-color", "transparent")
        $(this).css("background-color", "#24ac5f")
        $('div.sekundar').hide()
        $('.'+whatSubmenu).fadeIn()
        })

    /*IF you don't want the submenu disappear on mouseleave comment these lines of code*/
    $('div.sekundar').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).hide()
        $('li.principal').css("background-color", "transparent")
        })

})
</script>
```

html:

```
   <header>
       <nav id="primar">
            <ul>
                <li class="principal" id="li1"><a class="pointer">Indhold</a></li>
                <li class="principal" id="li2"><a class="pointer">Nyheder</a></li>
                <li class="principal" id="li3"><a class="pointer">Billeder</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="sekundar" class="sekundar i1">
        <nav class="nav2">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Osadff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Rwefewg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reehjy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="sekundar2" class="sekundar i2">
        <nav class="nav2">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">dgdgdg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sdfdfdg</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="sekundar3" class="sekundar i3">
        <nav class="nav2">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">defdgdgdg</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this simple example, you have a button that displays or hides your sub menu.
To verify if the menu is visible just give it a class using the toggleclass method and then check for the presence of that class.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#sekundar{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#test').click(function(){
       $('#sekundar').toggleClass('visible')
       if($('#sekundar').hasClass('visible')){
           alert('not visible')
           $('#sekundar').show()
           }else{
               alert('visible')
               $('#sekundar').hide()
           }
    })  

})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sekundar" class="sekundar">
    <nav class="nav2">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Opret Tekster</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rediger/Slet tekster</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rediger kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<input name="" type="button" value="check" id="test">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks,  but i have more than one submenu, but i have added this to them both, and made them so if i click one of them while the other one is visible it closes that and show the other. But when i click the second one i have to click 2 times before it closes the other and show it again?